# Adding issue types in Jira for developers

Tags: jira

Is it possible to create a new issue type in JIRA (as a project administrator) such that only admin/developers can create an issue of that type?

We want our admin/developers to be able to create these new issues, but not our users. (The users should be able to see issues of this new type, though).

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is "issue type scheme"

Taking from the docs

> What is an 'issue type scheme'? An 'issue type scheme' defines a
>   subset of issue types, which:
>
> restricts the set of available issue types for a project, and controls
>   the order of available issue types and the default issue type shown to
>   your users for a project.  The 'default issue type' is the issue type
>   displayed in the selection-box when a user creates an issue. A single
>   issue type scheme can be 're-used' across multiple projects, so that a
>   group of similar projects (i.e. projects which might be used for
>   similar purposes) can share the same issue type settings.

More info can be found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+Issue+Types+with+Projects)

Update: to set permissions and what an user can or can't see I am pretty sure you have to set "Issue security levels" I am not sure on how much you can change here but, according the docs you could

> "allow you to control who can see individual issues within a project
>   (subject to the project's permissions)."

You could see [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Issue-level+Security).

But I don't know if you have to be a Jira System Admin to set that, I really don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turns out that you need global admin status, and I am only admin. Do you (or anyone else) happen to know if this is possible to do as a global-admin? I still haven't seen any reference to issue types that can only be viewed, not created, by general users.

Comment: It turns out that being an admin isn't sufficient; one must be a global-admin. Therefore, I have passed this assignment on and will not be making this change personally. However, it looks like we were on the right track here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with the [permission scheme](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Permissions). Create a new scheme or copy an existing one, give the "Create Issues" permissions to the user groups you like, and apply the scheme onto the desired projects.

Comment: This link looks helpful, too. I think all of this would have been much more clear from the view of a global-admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Create the new issue type
Create a project that uses an issue type scheme that includes the new issue type
Restrict who can create issues in the project with the Create Issue in a copy of the default permission scheme

Answer (score -1):

Creating the issue type in JIRA can be done by navigating to **Settings > Issues > Add Issue Type**

[image: Add issue JIRA]

From there you can edit the Issue type and name.

[image: Add JIRA issue]

For more information, have a look at the [following link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+Issue+Type+Field+Values). If you need to configure issue level security, take a look at the [following document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Issue-level+Security) on the Atlassian documentation.

Comment: The original question was not just how to create an issue type. It was how to restrict who can create issues of a certain type.